# Python: If-else statements

Tags: python, if-statement

The following piece of code is showing an error:

```
if ((type(varA) or type(varB) ) == type('t')):
    print "string involved"
elif varA<varB:
    print "RANDOM"
```

the error is for this case:

```
Test Values: varA = 0, varB = adios
```

output:

```
RANDOM
```

while this other piece of code

```
if ((type(varA) == type('t')) or (type(varB)== type('t'))):
    print "string involved"
elif varA<varB:
    print "RANDOM"`
```

For the following test values:

```
Test Values: varA = 6, varB = adios
```

ouput is as follows:

```
string involved
```

What is the difference between these two "if" conditions? I am finding them to be of the same logic!

Comment: I don't know python, but I doubt you can do that. In most languages you can't compare `(a || b) == something`, when you mean `(a == something) || (b == something)`.

Comment: Why are you checking the type? The Python idiom is to seek forgiveness rather than permission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
if ((type(varA) or type(varB) ) == type('t')):
```

It should be:

```
if type(varA) == str or type(varB) == str:
```

Equivalently:

```
if isinstance(varA, str) or isinstance(varB, str):
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
if str in ((type(varA), type(varB)):
```

Comment: Does it really make semantic sense to use a tuple there? I would use a list.

Comment: or even `isinstance(varA, str) or isinstance(varB, str)`

Comment: @WaleedKhan it's the same, but for make it makes more sense to use a tuple, because the elements are not going to be modified

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Perhaps it's marginally faster, but a list is the semantically correct structure here and not a tuple, and therefore I think it makes more sense to use a list. Simply the idea that it won't change does not qualify it as a tuple.

Comment: @WaleedKhan that's precisely the definition of a tuple: an immutable sequence of elements, which is the case here (it's not a matter of efficiency, if that were the case a `set` might be better, depending on the number of elements). Take a look at some production code, perhaps an open source project, and you'll see that it's quite idiomatic to use a tuple in this case, not a list.

Comment: @WaleedKhan: I don't know about semantically correct or not, but it's definitely idiomatic to use a `tuple`.  There's been some movement in the last few years to start using a `set`, after the introduction of `set` literals, but not everything is hashable and the performance benefit for sequences so small you type them in manually is usually negligible.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez A tuple is meant to be an immutable *pairing* of elements, not a sequence. A list is a sequence of elements. Mutability has nothing to do with their definitions.

Comment: @WaleedKhan it's not a worthy discussion, just look at some real life code, and look at the documentation: it's an usage convention to use a tuple.

Comment: @DSM, Comparing with literal `set` is much less painful (efficiencywise) since Python3.3 which magically converts them to frozenset under the hood.

Comment: In fact, you can even look at the documentation for `isinstance`: `isinstance(object, class-or-type-or-tuple) -> bool`.  You can write `isinstance(a, (str, list))`, but you can't write `isinstance(a, [str, list])`; try it and see.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez The documentation: “Tuples are immutable, and usually contain an heterogeneous sequence of elements”, whereas “Lists are mutable, and their elements are usually homogeneous”. This clearly falls into the “homogeneous” category.

Comment: @WaleedKhan and clearly falls in the immutable category, too. Please, stop this discussion, I'm not interested anymore.

Comment: @WaleedKhan `import this` says "Although practicality beats purity." . In this case we know we're only ever going to call `__contains__` on this object, so we might as well use the most efficient type available for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this expression:

```
if ((type(varA) or type(varB) ) == type('t')):
```

Programming languages don't work like English.  The above first evaluates `type(varA) or type(varB)`, which will yield the type of `varA` - because `or` returns the first truthy value and any type is truthy.

Then it will check to see if that is the same as `type('t')` - that is, `str`.  Which means that it will only be true when `varA` is a string, and the type of `varB` is completely ignored.

What you want is probably this:

```
if type(varA) == type('t') or type(varB) == type('t'):
```

But there are more idiomatic/Pythonic ways of doing that; see Óscar López's answer for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the test to work well for subclasses of `str` as well it's a good idea to use `isintance` instead of `type`

```
if any(isinstance(x, str) for x in (varA, varB)):
    ...
```