# Python - Syntax for Boolean Expression with Type and Or

Tags: python, boolean

```
varA = 1

varB = 2
```

**Code w/ Correct Result:**

```
if type(varA) == type('a') or type(varB) == type('a'):
    print "string involved (either varA or varB is a string)"
else:
    print "varA and varB are not strings"
```

**Code w/ Incorrect Result:**

```
if type(varA) or type(varB) == type('a'):
    print "string involved (either varA or varB is a string)"
else:
    print "varA and varB are not strings"
```

Why exactly does the 2nd set of code not return the expected result (i.e. "varA and varB are not strings")? What is the step-by-step breakdown of what Python is doing with the 2nd set of code? I found a similar question had already been answered but did not entirely understand the explanation. [Python: If-else statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485061/python-if-else-statements).

Comment: The proper form will be __type(varA) is str__

Comment: possible duplicate of [if x or y or z == blah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah)

Comment: @volcano: the better form is `isinstance(varA, str)`, to allow for subclasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second code snippet, the condition of the if-statement is being interpreted by Python like this:

```
if (type(varA)) or (type(varB) == type('a')):
```

Moreover, it will *always* evaluate to `True`.

This is because, no matter what the value of `varA` is, `type(varA)` evaluates to `True`:

```
>>> varA = 'a'
>>> bool(type(varA))
True
>>> varA = False
>>> bool(type(varA))
True
>>>
```

In fact, since Python's logical operators short-circuit (stop evaluating as soon as possible), the `type(varB) == type('a')` part of the condition will never even be evaluated.

---

On a separate note, you should be using [`is`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is) to compare types:

```
if type(varA) is str or type(varB) is str:
```

or, you can use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(varA, str) or isinstance(varB, str):
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! So since {type(varA)} is always {True}, Python will always run the code corresponding to True regardless of the actual type of {varA}.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example does not work because it parses as

```
if (type(varA)) or (type(varB) == type('a')):
```

and `type(varA)` will always be a class type which is considered `True`, so the whole expression will be `True`

---

There are better ways to do this

```
if any(isinstance(v, str) for v in (varA, varB)):
```

`any` takes an iterable and evaluates to `True` if anything in the iterable is true.
`isinstance` checks to see if the first argument "is a" second argument.  Placing the generator expression inside of any reads as "if any v in (varA, varB) is a string): ... "

```
>>> var = 1
>>> isinstance(var, str) # var is an int, not a str
False
>>> isinstance(var, int)
True
>>> isinstance('a', int)
False
>>> isinstance('a', str) # 'a' is a str
True
```

Answer (score 0):

iCodez is absolutely correct, but if you really want to do something along the lines of "list all elements and check if one of them is a string":

```
if str in map(type, [varA, varB]):
    print "string involved"
```

Answer (score -1):

Because in the second case you are not comparing both variables. Any integer above 0 would return True so you are not comparing types here.

```
if type(varA):
```

will always be True, because varA is equal to 1. You never even get to the second part of the condition.

Comment: Wrong, type(0) is int.

Comment: Not what I said. type(0) is int, but it's also False according to python. Check: if 0 == False: print 123

Comment: type(varA) is not an integer. And any non-0 value - integer or float - evaluates to True in boolean expression. Here is my piece of code for you __if -1: print "Alex Hristov is wrong"__ ;-)

Comment: Look at the original post. **varA = 1** . varA is **clearly** an integer.